# using javascript regex, get meta tags data from a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tags, meta

I wanna get meta tags data using javascript(jquery) and regex.

Here are some meta tags.

```
<meta name="description" content="Amazon.com : Google Chromecast HDMI Streaming Media Player : Streaming Media Clients : Electronics" />
<meta name="title" content="Amazon.com : Google Chromecast HDMI Streaming Media Player : Streaming Media Clients : Electronics" />
```

I can get content from those forms using below function.

```
function getProductInfo(attr) {
    var m = $("meta[name="+attr+"]");
    var content = m.attr("content");
    return content; 
}
if(!title) var title = getProductInfo('title');
```

However sometimes there are different form of meta tags like

```
<meta property="title" content="....">
<meta property="og:title" content="....">
<meta name="title" description="....">
```

That's why I'm considering using regex. but I have no idea.
please give me a tip. thanks.

Comment: using clientside language does allow you only to get the metadata of your own site or sites wich have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'. you need php/asp or yql to get the metadata from remote sites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how you do it by [not using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

No libraries, pure vanilla JS:

```
var meta = document.querySelectorAll('meta');
for(var i=0;i<meta.length;i++){
   var content = meta[i].getAttribute('content'); /* here's the content */
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/JA9Yq/**

jQuery:

```
$('meta').each(function(index,tag){
    var content = tag.getAttribute('content');
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/duL6E/**

Comment: He wants specific name/property content  e.g 'title'

Answer (score 2):

Its also possible using RegEx:

```
<meta[^>]+content="([^")]*)"
```

Result:

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <meta name="description" content="Amazon.com : Google Chromecast HDMI Streaming Media Player : Streaming Media Clients : Electronics"
        [1] => <meta name="title" content="Amazon.com : Google Chromecast HDMI Streaming Media Player : Streaming Media Clients : Electronics"
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Amazon.com : Google Chromecast HDMI Streaming Media Player : Streaming Media Clients : Electronics
        [1] => Amazon.com : Google Chromecast HDMI Streaming Media Player : Streaming Media Clients : Electronics
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks, this was the start to the solution I needed.  I needed to include right angle bracket too: <meta[^>]+content="([^")]*).*?>

Answer (score 1):

```
$('meta').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('content'));
    });
```

No need for regex, for unsorted tags.

```
function getProductInfo(attr) {
            $('meta').each(function(index,tag) {
                if($(tag)[0].attributes[0].textContent == attr) { 
                        console.log($(tag)[0].attributes[0].textContent, $(tag)[0].attributes[1].textContent);
                     }
            });
        }
        getProductInfo('title');
```

This will get you anything , that has title in name/property.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on all meta tags I think...

```
    /\<meta.*?\>/
```

Here's a link to regexr, which is a good tool to try things out

http://gskinner.com/RegExr

But it's better to use @subZero advice and not use regex if you don't have to... I think.

Answer (score 0):

may be this..

```
var desc = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
var title= $('meta[name=title]').attr("content");

var desc = $('meta[property=description]').attr("content");
var title= $("meta[property='og:title]").attr("content");
```

note: Apparently it doesn't like the colon. I was able to fix it by using double and single quotes like this: